# Best place to put my IRouteConstraint implementations in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC project, where is the best place to put my classes that implement IRouteConstraint in order to keep it organized and stay true to the structure of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is put all routing base classes and helper classes in a routing folder. Then have more specific classes in subfolders.

Answer (score 2):

I am investing in a separate project with generic MVC definitions like route constraints and custom (but generic) ActionResult-based types. The MVC Web Project then references the genreric MVC Class project.

Comment: +1: It makes sense when there is a lot of such classes. It could be a class library with `Company.Product.Mvc` namespace!